# If the limit of f(x) is infinity, does it mean its reciprocal is zero?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do we prove that $$\lim_{x \to c} f(x)= \infty.$$and  $$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{1}{f(x)}= 0.$$
are the same by using their precise definitions?

I cannot seem to get a correlation between both statements even after writing out the precise definition of an infinite limit.

Comment: This is, for sure , a duplicate and has been asked on this site many times : let me go over the site for about a minute or 2 and I'll get back with some helpful posts.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038716/using-definition-of-limits?noredirect=1) could do your job, and so could [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535303/if-fx-has-infinite-limit-as-x-approaches-infinity-1-fx-approaches-0?noredirect=1) and here is an [AoPS post about it](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h497858p2797261), each of which contain complete answers to your question. I have voted to close this question as a duplicate of the first question I attached, but it's your call on whether it does the job or not. If it doesn't, let me know.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome! Note that you can search for these questions using the MSE search engine [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/). I typed "$\lim f(x) = \infty$ $\lim \frac 1{f(x)} = 0$" into the search box and got the results. If you use the search box you will most likely not need to wait for answers!

Comment: These two are equivalent if $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in domain of $f$.  Otherwise we can guarantee it. Consider the example $f:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\frac1x$. Then clearly $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{f(x)}=0$ but $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ is not $\infty$.